# FileObserver not reacting to CREATE

Tags: android, fileobserver

I'm trying to make an app that will react to screenshots folder and do a toast for beginning, 
I'm a new developer and this is my first time using file observer so I can only guess I've made a lot of mistakes. 
The problem is there is no toast or log upon taking a screenshot.
Here is the code in my observer class:

```
public class listeningInit extends FileObserver {
private static final String TAG = "File listener";
public String absolutePath;
public listeningInit(String path) {
    super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
    absolutePath = path;
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    if ((FileObserver.CREATE & event)!=0) {
        Log.v(TAG, absolutePath + "/" + path + " is created\n");
        Context context = getContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Folder action!", duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}

private Context getContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

and here's the code on activity that does .startWatching

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listeningInit startObs = new listeningInit("/Pictures/Screenshots/");
    startObs.startWatching();

    //Checking if this is a first run
    Boolean firstRun = false;
    SharedPreferences run = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
    firstRun = run.getBoolean("fr", true);
    //if true launch tutorial activity 
    if(firstRun == true){
        Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tutorial.class);
        startActivity(k);
    }
}
```

There's no errors thrown by the code, it's just not responding and I don't have a slight clue on why that might be.

Comment: First "/Pictures/Screenshots/" seems incorrect as a path, it should be prefixed with the base path of the external storage.  If that doesn't fix it, I'd try testing the code somewhere in your app's private directory (with a button to create a file) to make sure you are using the FileObserver correctly; lastly I'd explore the possibility that the current *emulated* implementation of external storage might conceivable be breaking the linux kernel implementation of inotify on which FileObserver depends.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've tried setting it to storage/emulated/0/pictures... and 0/Pictures.. neither worked. I'll try to use fileObs inside app tomorrow, it's kinda late now and how do you mean emuleted could be breaking inotify? shouldn't it work as a standard?

Comment: How about trying to have your program open a known-to-exist picture in order to temporarily test the path, which you should be obtaining with the external storage APIs (and which incidentally will appear to be in a different place for your app than it will be in for the adb shell).  In terms of the emulated storage, my (speculative) point was that the way Android currently does it is fairly unusual, and might cause incompatibility.  But that is highly speculative; first we need to know that you are watching the right place.

Comment: Have you looked at DexLoaderTest code in AOSP?  https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/94475bdfffb535c2cbdee9745439329da09d068c/chrome/android/webapk/shell_apk/javatests/src/org/chromium/webapk/shell_apk/DexLoaderTest.java